# Using Twisted to track GPS Locations on an iPhone

Tags: ios, twisted

Recently, while developing an app on the iPhone, I came across the problem of tracking vehicles.  It was easy to track the vehicles on a map if they were stationary using Parse ( although not sure if it was the best method) but the issue was tracking vehicles if they were moving.  I didn't want to query for geopoints in Parse unnecessarily if the location of the vehicle did not change.  I was steered towards using Twisted, and after doing some investigation, realized this might be a solution.  Using the reactor loop, when locations were changed I could notify the other users and update their maps appropriately. Conceptually, I understand this problem but having trouble finding information or help regarding GPS with twisted.

I currently have been running the gps example from the site, http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/core/examples/gpsfix.py

Using my MacBook pro to test, I found the available serial port and it attempts to open as a NMEAReciever but I was expecting a GPS location to be written. Once I can understand how to interact with the GPS, I feel I could tackle communicating this information through the iPhone with NSStreams such in the fashion of this tutorial except instead of sending text messages, it will be sending GPS locations
 http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

Overall, my question is how can I access the GPS coordinates of a device using Twisted through the tutorial provided. I hope my question was detailed enough and I would be more than happy to correspond with someone any more details. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (eventually) wrote twisted.positioning, which is essentially a better version of the `twisted.protocols.gps` thing you're using. It has much nicer abstractions over concepts like positions, as well as receivers. That may be interesting to you, because it provides abstractions that you can use to e.g. combine information from GPS and other sources (like compass). However, I think that in iOS-land, that job is already (mostly) handled by Core Location. I'd assume that the best course of action is too hook that up to `twisted.positioning` (shouldn't be *particularly* difficult, can't be anywhere nearly as hard as NMEA is, at least!). Lacking iOS development experience, I can't tell you how to access Core Location from Python; I can only point at [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html).

`twisted.positioning` is also an improvement when it comes to documentation. Unfortunately, that wasn't very difficult, because its predecessor came with none at all. I hope [the one scant example that is provided](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/positioning.html) helps, though; and I'd be more than happy to elaborate if it doesn't.

Comment: awesome, just reading it looks a lot nicer to understand and implement.  Do I need to download the latest version of Twisted? It can't find the positioning module

Comment: i installed released 14.0.0 and it still says cant find the positioning module

Comment: It was introduced in 14.0.0.  Make sure you're actually using the new version you installed and not some other version already on the system.  Remember, `sudo pip install ...` or `sudo easy_install ...` is not your friend.  Stick custom Python module dependencies into a virtualenv to avoid ruining your system and your other Python projects.

Comment: i typed twistd --version to check what version is being used and it reads 14.0.0

Comment: i created a virtual environment, activated it, installed twistd by typing install twistd, reads that 14.0.0 is installed, and still the module positioning is not found

Comment: sorry to be a noob, I'm not used to python only c based languages so I'm trying to get this working so i can start working with twistd

Comment: It should definitely be available. Can you show me the exact Python statement you used to try to import it, and the exact way it failed?

Comment: @lvh i finally got it compiling and know am able to run the python on my MacBook, unfortunately I'm assuming no GPS position is recieved because the MacBook has no GPS.  However, if I were to use this and test on my iPhone, what would the name of the serial port be? Am i barking up the wrong tree trying to find GPS locations with Twisted on an iPhone besides ones own.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how it works on iOS :-( As I mentioned before, it may be a better idea to try and hook up Python to CoreLocation and use a twisted.positioning adapter for it.